# Why Visual Studio allow const const int in C++ but not in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, constants

Why when I tried to type `const const int num = 10;` in Visual Studio and it allowed however In the Eclipse it didn 't allowed.

I just curious why Visual Studio could allowed this Or is there have any effects when `const const int num = 10 ;` in Visual Studio.

And I am just using Visual Studio 2012 and Eclipse Luna for testing.

Comment: Do you mean the *editor* "allowed it", or the *compiler*?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `const const`?

Comment: both editor and compiler are allowed as well as if normally input int int num = 10; is not allowed but interestingly it can be compile and no error but warning in Visual Studio 2012 for const const int num = 10;

Comment: So you're asking which compiler is more standards compliant?

Comment: And I think that effect in visual studio const const int num = 10; is more or less as similar as const int num = 10;

Comment: No,I just curious why Visual Studio is allowed these special syntax

Comment: afaik visual studio needs some tweaking to be standard compliant

Answer (score 2):

The statement `const const int num = 10;` is ill-formed, and a compiler should issue an error.

You can control the behavior of Visual Studio. By default, it issues warning [C4114](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9db2t0x.aspx), when the same type qualifier is used more than once. Using the [/Za](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) compiler switch produces error [C2289](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxat9893.aspx) instead:

> A type declaration or definition uses a type qualifier (const, volatile, signed, or unsigned) more than once. This causes a warning with Microsoft extensions (/Ze) and an error under ANSI compatibility (/Za).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.